# How to handle routes in Github Pages?

Tags: react-router, github-pages

I have a react app published on github pages, my hompage and repository is `/websiteName`  so it's working when I'm at the hompage, ex: `username.github.io/websiteName`. But I also have a route which is `/user/:id`, so when I click a link it will redirect me to `username.github.io/user/123` thus giving me a 404 error. So how do I fix the 404 error when redirecting to a different route other than `/websiteName`.

**Edit**

I now added hash router, but when I click a Link with a path of `/user/:id`, it redirects me to `https://username.github.io/websiteName/#/user/123`. Then it gives me a blank page.

```
  <HashRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={User} />
    <Route path="/user/:slug" component={Info} />
  </HashRouter>
```

when I add a basename of /websiteName I get double slashes because my homepage name on package.json

Comment: Use the hash mode of the browser router.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you please supply us your implementation of react router ?